# $p$,$q$ and $r$ are roots of $x^3+2x^2+3x+3=0$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots

$p$,$q$ and $r$ are roots of $x^3+2x^2+3x+3=0$. Find value of

$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{p}{p+1}\right)^3$$

I have modified the equations as  $$(x+1)^3=x^2-2$$ so

$$ \frac{x^3}{(x+1)^3}=\frac{x^3}{x^2-2}=x+\frac{1}{x-\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{2}}$$ So

$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{p}{p+1}\right)^3=\sum_{cyc}p+\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{p-\sqrt{2}}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{p+\sqrt{2}}$$

After this i have find equation whose roots are $p-\sqrt{2}$, $q-\sqrt{2}$ and $r-\sqrt{2}$ and similarly for other cyclic expression. but its too lengthy

Comment: At that point, I would probably expand the cyclic sums you already have and apply [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Answer (score 4):

There is an easier way if $y=\frac{1}{x}$ then $y$ is a root of 
$$3y^3+3y^2+2y+1=0$$ if $z=y+1$ then $z$ is a root of

$$3z^3-6z^2-6z-2=0$$ and if $w=\frac{1}{z}$ then $w$ is a root of 
$$2w^3+6w^2+6w-3=0$$ and in the highly unlikely event I have not made a mistake, you can use Newton formula to find the sum of the cubes of the roots of this last equation.

Comment: I get that if $k = \frac{x}{x+1}$ for $x^3+2x^2+3x+3 = 0$, then $k$ is a root of $k^3-5k^2+6k-3$. Take $x = -\frac{k}{k-1}$ and plug it into $x^3+2x^2+3x+3$ to get $$-\frac{k^3}{(k-1)^3}+\frac{2k^2}{(k-1)^2}-\frac{3k}{k-1}+3 = \frac{k^3-5k^2+6k-3}{(k-1)^3} = 0$$ Then apply [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Comment: @MichaelLee ok so I made a mistake, is this a surprise  ?